# 'beresp.ttl': cannot be set in method 'vcl_hit' in Varnish 4.0

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to import my old Varnish configuration to version 4.0.

```
sub vcl_hit {
     if (req.method == "PURGE") {
          set beresp.ttl = 0s;
          return (synth(200, "Purged."));
     }
}
```

Error I am getting:

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
'beresp.ttl': cannot be set in method 'vcl_hit'.
At: ('input' Line 135 Pos 15)
          set beresp.ttl = 0s;
--------------##########------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
```

So how do I update that?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not working ;) there is a complete migrate guide how to migrate from 3 to 4

https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html

Here is a complete list what has changed and how you can fix it.

Comment: That url now seems to be broken. This should work -- https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html

Comment: @AlexVolkov yes you're right but i can't find a new one.

Comment: This answer is not really useful. The linked page does not contain the answer to the above problem, and the OP already knew that beresp.ttl does not work there in varnish 4. This answer also does not answer the question asked. I guess one answer is "delete the `set beresp.ttl` line (I ended up doing just that), but that is still not that useful.

Comment: I have updated the link. Normally you can find everything in the migration guides.